# Ubuntu 16.04 LTS wi-fi goes offline

Tags: networking, drivers

I have problem with my home laptop. My wi-fi adapter goes offline randomly. These are the specifications of my wi-fi adapter:

```
   Wireless interface
   product: RT3290 Wireless 802.11n 1T/1R PCIe
   vendor: Ralink corp.
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
   logical name: wlo1
   version: 00
   serial: bc:85:56:f4:95:ff
   width: 32 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
   configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rt2800pci driverversion=4.4.0-57-generic firmware=0.37 ip=192.168.0.90 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bgn
```

I tried to update, delete, and install the driver but it doesn't seem to work. In random time intervals, my laptop goes offline.

Comment: Update:
Light of wi-fi adapter is colored with red light,but i have internet.Strange...

Answer (score 0):

I have also noticed Ubuntu WiFi drivers in general are too often not properly tuned to play nicely with random wifi router hardware and so drop off connections or fail to connect especially at questionable public wifi locations like libraries ... sadly I resort to using my cell phone as a wifi hotspot to band aid the situation, not a sustainable solution especially at home

Luckily at home you have control over your router ... I suggest you view your wifi landscape and move your router channel onto the quietest possible  ... on android the free app: `Wifi Analyzer` will give you plots like this

[image]

where the red network called `gone fishing` is mine and its not competing with noisy neighbors ... if above landscape matches yours the the below suggestion will not help your situation ... whereas the following wifi landscape also shown using above mentioned app shows my network `thefloat` which may well benefit from moving the router channel from current 6 to channel 8

[image]

All routers allow you to login to the router and change settings like its output frequency channel.  Google your router make/model ... typically its address is something like    http://192.168.1.1/   believe it or not a typical router login could be :    YMMV

```
    login :   leave blank  
    paswd :   admin
```

rummage around to change the channel setting .... Alternatively you can always solve this bad wifi driver issue by skipping the wifi and plug in an ethernet cable from your laptop to the router ;-)